# Hide div after clicking button in that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to delete or hide div when I click the button. The problem is that I have a lot of divs and I want to make delete the specific div where I clicked button.

My divs:

```
              <div class="col-sm-4 col--remove">
                    <div class="post post--preview">
                        <form class="akcje_konkretne" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" name="usun" value="usun" class="btn read-more post--btn usun">usuń</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-4 col--remove">
                    <div class="post post--preview">
                        <form class="akcje_konkretne" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" name="usun" value="usun" class="btn read-more post--btn usun">usuń</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-4 col--remove">
                    <div class="post post--preview">
                        <form class="akcje_konkretne" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" name="usun" value="usun" class="btn read-more post--btn usun">usuń</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-4 col--remove">
                    <div class="post post--preview">
                        <form class="akcje_konkretne" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" name="usun" value="usun" class="btn read-more post--btn usun">usuń</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
              </div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('form.actionlist').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);

     //Tried with:
$(this).hide();
$(this).closest('.col-sm-4 col--remove').hide();
$('.col-sm-4 col--remove').hide();

     });
```

Dont know how to do it, how I can hide div where I clicked button?

Comment: Look at .parent() try $(this).parent().parent().hide()

Comment: Did one of these answers resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty close. Two problems:

1. You're attaching your `submit()` event handler to forms classed as `actionlist`, but your forms are actually classed as `akcje_konkretne`.
2. Your `closest()` selector ("`.col-sm-4 col--remove`") contains a space, but not a second `.`. As written, this looks for the "col--remove" element within the closest element classed as "col-sm-4". Instead, you were trying to look for the closest element that is classed as *both* "col-sm-4" and "col--remove": `closest('.col-sm-4.col--remove')`.

But there's an even better way...

**If you want the *outer* div**, try:

```
$('form.akcje_konkretne').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('div.col--remove').hide(); //or remove(), if that's what you want
});
```

I'm guesing the `.col--remove` class is used to indicate "this is the div you want to remove".

You can [view this approach in action](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/fpxL64gs/) (note the outer div has a red border, the inner div has a blue border).

**If you want the *closest* div** (the one immediately wrapping the `form` getting submitted), try:

```
$('form.akcje_konkretne').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('div').hide(); //or remove(), if that's what you want
});
```

You can [view this approach in action](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/98smcd6w/).

Answer (score 3):

Just a little mistake :

```
$(this).closest('.col-sm-4.col--remove').hide();
```

the control has both class so you need to chain it in the selector.